# parse the below json with jquery and display data in a html table

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json

I need to parse the below json with jquery  and display in a html table.

display the values of "key"  and "doc_count" in a html table.

Help is appreciated. see json below:

{
    "key": "A",
    "count": 100
},
{
    "key": "AB",
    "count": 800
}

Comment: so what you tried for that ?

Comment: See datatables, that's what I use and it works perfectly

Comment: .aggregations.2.buckets not working?

Comment: http://www.dynatable.com/

Comment: any idea how to do this with jquery?

Comment: dynatable uses jquery, its easy to use

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try This code:

Use any Template Engine(Handlebars or Underscore) to process HTML. I am assuming data is in the form of Static Json.

Make a table and append to HTML page:

```
var Table=$("<table class='json_data'>");
$('body').append(Table);
```

Then iterate whole Json to get the desired value.Like this:

```
$.each(parse_json.aggregations[2].buckets,function(index,value){
   $('.json_data').append("<tr><td>"+value.key+"</td><td>"+value.doc_count+"</td></tr>");
})
```

JSFiddle Link: https://jsfiddle.net/Dee0565/17u4xs3s/