# parse json with jquery and display data in a html table

Tags: jquery, html, json

I need to parse the below json with jquery and display in a html table.
Display the values of  `key` and `count` in a html table. The output should look like this.

```
{
    "key": "A",
    "count": 100
},
{
    "key": "AB",
    "count": 800
}
```

Any help is highly appreciated!

Comment: please go to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33824676/parse-the-below-json-with-jquery-and-display-data-in-a-html-table/33825321#33825321

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try the following:

```
var table = $("table");
var json = '{"took":32,"timed_out":false,"aggregations":{"2":{"doc_count_error_upper_bound":0,"sum_other_doc_count":447529,"buckets":[{"3":{"doc_count_error_upper_bound":2804,"sum_other_doc_count":152552,"buckets":[{"key":"d4","doc_count":6882},{"key":"r3","doc_count":6494}]},"rootkey":"AAA","doc_count":165928},{"3":{"doc_count_error_upper_bound":1574,"sum_other_doc_count":82914,"buckets":[{"key":"in","doc_count":4289},{"key":"d3","doc_count":3516}]},"rootkey":"BBB","doc_count":90719}]}}}';
json = $.parseJSON(json);
$.each(json.aggregations["2"].buckets, function(i, n){
    var rootkey = n.rootkey;
    n = n["3"];
    $.each(n.buckets, function(e, r){
        table.append("<tr><td>"+rootkey+"</td><td>"+r.key+"</td><td>"+r.doc_count+"</td></tr>");
    });
});
```

[JSFiddle Here](http://jsfiddle.net/f26h95k8/)